How to change background color of st.text_input() in streamlit?
I am trying to change the background color of st.text_input() box but unable to do so.
I am not from web/app development background or with any html css skills so please excuse my naive or poor understanding in this field.
So far I have tried:
using this link
test_color = st.write('test color')

def text_input_color(url):
    st.markdown(
        f'<p style="background-color:#0066cc;color:#33ff33;">{url}</p>', unsafe_allow_html=True
    )

text_input_color("test_color")

Above code works on st.write() but not on st.text_input()
I have also come across this link so using this approach and I have modified css for Textinput instead of stForm but this also didn't work and I am not sure what id to use for text input
css="""
<style>
    [data-testid="stTextinput"] {
        background: LightBlue;
    }
</style>
"""

Below is the inspect element screenshot of the webapp:


st.markdown("<style> .st-bd { background-color: LightBlue; } </style>", unsafe_allow_html=True) ?

@Timeless Thanks alot, Appreciate 'ur help. This worked. Please add this to the answer so that I accept it to close this Post.

@Timeless how do you get to know its .st-bd and not .st-bb or .st-b7 or some other ?

I wouldn't rely on classes like .st-bd, .st-bb, or .st-b7 they are dynamically generated by Streamlit and can change (versions or runs). I would rather use aria-label.

import streamlit as st

st.markdown("""
<style>
    .stTextInput input[aria-label="test color"] {
        background-color: #0066cc;
        color: #33ff33;
    }
    .stTextInput input[aria-label="test color2"] {
        background-color: #cc0066;
        color: #ffff33;
    }
</style>
""", unsafe_allow_html=True)

st.text_input("test color")
st.text_input("test color2")


That makes sense. Thanks alot. Appreciate your help and explanation of selection.
